# Issues with Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, search

We have a dutch website build with Craft CMS and for the webshop Craft CMS Commerce. This has been done by a design company. We don't receive any orders and I am wondering if the whole process is okay. Translate version in English will be launched in September. Als the search filter is not working properly. Can someone have a look at it and could give me some reply? I can do the standard items in the backend from Craft but no codes. The webshop is: www.hulshofbusinesscases.com. Thanks for listening and maybe you help. Greetings Marina

Comment: Welcome to craftcms.SE! Unfortunately, this question is far too broad to be able to provide a useful answer. I'd recommend following Clive's suggestion, and get in touch with your developer.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to get in touch with the developers or find some new developers. But run a test purchase for peace of mind anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it everything is working fine.

I obviously did not buy the product, but until the final checkout, everything worked as expected.